# App Transport Security blocks HTTPS

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I've a problem with ATS.
I'm using XCode 9.1, my Development Target is 11.0.
I'm developing using react-native 0.49

My program is doing a fetch to a **https** (https://www.xxxx.com) resource which has a valid (google chrome) letsencrypt certificate.
The fetch only works, when NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is set to true, when set to false the fetch is blocked (debug out)?

I'm doing some tests using a temporary domain (https://xxxx.no-ip.org). This domain also has a valid letsencrypt certificate. In this case everything works fine.

The only difference I can see between both hosts is that the test domain is a single domain host, the production host is a multi domain host.
Anybody a suggestion?

Regards,

Harry

---

**The debug out:**
*CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:1187] 12:38:08.258 {
           Did Fail: (null)
             Loader:  {url = https://....
              Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}*

This is my **info.plist** section

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
  <key>xxxx.no-ip.org</key>
  <dict/>
  <key>localhost</key>
  <dict>
  <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
  <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>xxxx.com</key>
  <dict>
  <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
  <true/>
</dict>  </dict>  </dict>
```

Comment: How do you know the cert on (`https://www.xxxx.com`) is valid? Letsencrypt does not issue *.example.com certs -- are you sure yours is for www.xxxx.com, and not just xxxx.com?

Comment: I've opened the URL in Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` shouldn't do anything if you are trying to connect via HTTPS.  Is it possible that your URL (https://www.xxxx.com) is redirecting traffic to http://www.xxxx.com?

There are other exceptions that will affect HTTPS traffic that will allow HTTPS connections that don't satisfy all the requirements for HTTPS (e.g. Forward Secrecy, TLS version, key strength).  What you need to do is to figure out exactly why it is failing.

To test the URL for ATS compliance, use the `nscurl --ats-diagnostics <url>` command on your Mac. You can find out more about ATS in general, as well is how to use / interpret the results of the nscurl command above in [this post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/app-transport-security/).

Additionally, you could bump up the logging to get more details as to why it is failing by changing your `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` level up. You can find out more about that [here](http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.com/2015/07/using-cfnetworkdiagnostics-for-network.html).

Comment: Thx for your advise! I do not redirect to http. But there is a difference: xxx.no-ip.org (which works fine) can be reached via http and https. www.xxxx.com only can be reached via https.

Comment: I've done - many informations. I'm going to analyze and compare it on weekend ...

Comment: hi wottlet, thank you once more! using ncurl I've found the valid settings. I thought both systems are using certs of the same authority, so I've used the same settings. This was my missunderstanding, they are distinguished by different openssl versions.

Comment: @HarryBauer If the nscurl command helped you troubleshoot your problem, consider accepting the answer so others with similar symptoms can use it in the future if they find your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens because your certificate doesn't fit all the requirements of TLS version that Apple requires.

Try adding this to the domain https://www.xxxx.com

```
<key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<true/>
```

And don't forget to include subdomains:

```
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
```

If that doesn't help then you can try to find what is the minimum TLS version you want to support too:

```
<key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.2</string>
```

If all the past ones don't work, try adding this:

```
<key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Thx Gabox, I've already played with these parameters - unfortunately without success. The certificat is quite new (SHA-256 with RSA-Encryption) and its practically the same cert like on my test-host. All major Browsers like Chrome and Safari are accepting the certificate without any difficulty - its strange ...

Comment: weird, so if no one of these worked on your domain I would say that the cert doesn't fit the requirements from Apple then.
I have seen situations where the domain needs the exception for `ForwardSecrecy` which is the common one.

Comment: Safari will accept the cert even if it doesn't meet the ATS requirements.  Otherwise, half of the internet would stop working in Safari.  There are so many websites out there that don't meet the minimum ATS requirements (TLS 1.2+, forward secrecy, strong key).